# Separar dados na tabela

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Eu gostaria de fazer uma tabela separada por "temporadas". Exemplo:

```
Tabela estatisticas:
Temporada 1:
    ID | JOGADOR | PTS | AST |
    0  | Leonard | 12  | 7   |
    1  | Pedro   | 10  | 5   |
    Temporada 2:
    ID | JOGADOR | PTS | AST |
    0  | Leonard | 08  | 02  |
    1  | Pedro   | 09  | 03  |
```

Gostaria que fosse apenas uma tabela, isso é possível? Se sim como eu posso fazer?

Comment: Caso a resposta esteja certa, por favor não se esqueça de marcar como correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só adicionar uma coluna a mais, não?
Como ficaria:

```
ALTER TABLE estatisticas ADD COLUMN 'temporada' INT(1) NOT NULL FIRST;
```

E quando for fazer o select:

```
SELECT * FROM estatisticas ORDER BY temporada ASC;
```

Comment: Eu poderia adicionar dois jogadores iguais com temporadas diferentes?

Comment: Sim, mas o nome do jogador nem o ID pode ser `unique`.

Comment: O certo mesmo seria você ter uma tabela só para os jogadores e outra para as estatísticas, dai você faria uma chave estrangeira para o ID do jogador.

Comment: Eu tenho uma tabela apenas para os jogadores, como eu faria isso?

Comment: Pode me mostrar suas tabelas?

Comment: tabela players: http://i.imgur.com/IoF2MVR.png e tabela stats: http://i.imgur.com/DrdNZdx.png

Comment: No seu caso, a maneira do qual eu fiz na resposta cabe bem.